# Tabpage horizontal scroll bar issue on Datagridview combobox entry event in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, scrollbar, tabpage

I have a tab page which has got a Datagridview having multiple columns which creates need for horizontal scroll bar. I was not able to add scrollbar on DGV so added on tabpage. But when I scroll to right and make an entry on any of the Combobox field my tabpage scrollbar scrolls to the left. Which is bit annoying when you have multiple columns to select value in.

Is there a better way of adding a scroll bar or how to resolve this issue using scroll on tabpage?

I had a cellvaluechanged event for Grid which I commented but still getting same issue. Also I tried adding scrollbar to DGV but it was not adding any scrolls.

Also tried with Autosizemode for columns to fill and other values but that has also not helped.